# Flashlight Dimming Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, flashlight

When I put your flashlight dimmer coding into my app, I get this error
"local declaration 'slider' hides instance variable"

Here is the code:

```
UISlider *slider = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20.0f, 20.0f, 280.0f, 40.0f)];
slider.maximumValue = 1.0f;
slider.minimumValue = 0.0f;
[slider setContinuous:YES];
[slider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[self.view addSubview:slider];
```

Comment: Please don't make another flashlight app!

Comment: Let him earn some $$$$ tooo

Comment: possible duplicate of [Local declaration 'theslider' hides instance variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15672821/local-declaration-theslider-hides-instance-variable)

Comment: rename your _local_ variable (to e.g. `slider1`) and your problem will be resolved; or use the global `slider` property instead of creating a new _local_ variable.

Answer (score 0):

The error means there is a variable named `slider` somewhere in your app that is already declared. If you simply rename your variable, the error should go away.

And for Steve's sake, please don't make another flashlight app!

Answer (score 0):

`"local declaration 'slider' hides instance variable"`

This is straight forward. You need to change either of the name,

Preferably change local slider to someother name as:

```
UISlider *localSlider = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20.0f, 20.0f, 280.0f, 40.0f)];
UISlider *slider = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20.0f, 20.0f, 280.0f, 40.0f)];
localSlider .maximumValue = 1.0f;
localSlider .minimumValue = 0.0f;
[localSlider setContinuous:YES];
[localSlider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[self.view localSlider];
```

Comment: When i changed the slider to local slider it then says unused variable??

Comment: You need to change all the local `slider` to `localSlider`

Comment: - (void)sliderDidChange:(UISlider *)slider                            says undeclared identifier 'sliderdidchange'

Comment: in that method you are using that name which is not declared.

Comment: show the full code, better to ask a new question if it is tooo long

Comment: - (void)sliderDidChange:(UISlider *)slider
{
   AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
   [device lockForConfiguration:nil];
   [device setTorchModeOnWithLevel:slider.value error:NULL];
   [device unlockForConfiguration];
    }

Comment: it says it for - (void)sliderDidChange:(UISlider *)slider

Answer (score 0):

You have declared your local variable 'slider' with the same name as a previously declared instance variable.  You need to either change the name of the instance variable, or the local variable, and all will be well.